# Scala - Spark Streaming and Twitter

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have been trying to build a program in Scala to use stream tweets. My issue is while building the program.

I am getting this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/streaming/twitter/TwitterUtils$
```

I believe there is something wrong in the sbt file. I have tried different configurations and none of them has worked. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

I am aware of this thread with a similar problem: [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/streaming/twitter/TwitterUtils$ while running TwitterPopularTags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28165032/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-spark-streaming-twitter-twitterutils)

This my current sbt file

```
name := "Tweets"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.4.0"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming_2.10" % "1.4.0"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming-twitter_2.10" % "1.4.0"
```

Thanks

Comment: The linked ticket has the most plausible culprit: create an uber jar via sbt-assembly.

Answer (score 0):

i tested this example , and had similar issue , the solution was creating a folder "lib" in the project path and put all the required jars manually to in this folder , hope this solution works for you