# streaming example on scala ide

Tags: apache-spark, scala-ide

When im running spark streaming example on scala ide. im getting below error, could any one help me please ?

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/util/ShutdownHookManager$

Comment: it looks like reference issue. maybe you can follow this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28165032/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-spark-streaming-twitter-twitterutils