# org.apache.spark.streaming.twitter not found

Tags: apache-spark, streaming

When I am trying to include org.apache.spark.streaming.twitter into spark shell 
The following error occurred " object twitter is not a member of package org.apache.spark.streaming"

Can someone help me in solving this by adding jars or changing conf file or whatever? Could you please post the step by step process.

Thanks,

Comment: you need to download **spark-streaming-twitter_2.10-1.0.0.jar** and after that you have to pass this jar to spark shell - something like : `spark-shell --jars spark-streaming-twitter_2.10-1.0.0.jar`

Comment: Please provide more detail, e.g. commands you have executed, software versions etc. It is hard to tell where exactly the error comes from with just an error message and a very abstract description.

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28165032/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-spark-streaming-twitter-twitterutils/33223770#33223770